# Como pasar datos en funcion del input con un select al controlador

Tags: php, html

Buenas a todos y gracias por su interés, tengo un problema y es que intento crear un formulario con 2 inputs y un select, cada uno manda un dato distinto al controlador php,

```
<form method="post" action = "{$link->getModuleLink('krack', 'listadoMercancia')}">
                <input name='op' value='add' type='hidden'>
                <input name='up' value='del' type='hidden'>
                <select name="select_tiendas" id="tiendas" class="form-control select_destino_envio">
                        {foreach $tiendas as $tienda}
                            <option value="{$tienda.id_store}" data-name="{$tienda.name}" select="selected"> {$tienda.name}</option>
                        {/foreach}
                </select>
                <div class="row boton_grabar_envio">
                    <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-default boton_borde" name="addBulto" id="boton_grabar_envio">
                        <span>
                            {l s='Grabar bulto'}
                            <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="submit" class="button btn btn-default boton_borde" name="remBulto" id="boton_restar_envio">
                        <span>
                            {l s='Restar bulto'}
                            <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

La idea seria, que cuando tu pulsas el primer botón( "agregar" ) te llame al mismo método que el segundo, pero con el input con el valor add, añade a la base de datos y con el "del" o "rem" tiene un if else, que decide si hace un insert o el otro.
Mi problema viene aquí, ya que solo me deja recoger el ultimo input y el id, no me coge el que selecciono, sin embargo si quito 1 input si que me recoge el dato y valor correcto, como podría hacer para programarle que con el botón de "restar" recoja el valor del input "del" y el valor seleccionado del select?

No se si me he explicado muy bien...

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola. Me surgen un par de dudas: ¿Dónde está el botón agregar al que haces referencia, te refieres al de "grabar bulto"? ¿Quieres que según pulses ese botón se cargue este formulario con el select en un valor predeterminado? ¿Dónde reocges los inputs? ¿Si el programa sirve para sumar o restar productos porque usas dos inputs diferentes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido solucionarlo, poniendo simplemente el value que le asignada a los inputs y el name en los botones, con lo cual me sobraban el código resultante al final es este por si alguien lo necesita:

Muchas gracias a todos por sus aportaciones. Saludos.

```
<form method="post" action = "{$link->getModuleLink('krack', 'listadoMercancia')}">
            <select name="select_tiendas" id="tiendas" class="form-control select_destino_envio">
                    {foreach $tiendas as $tienda}
                        <option value="{$tienda.id_store}" data-name="{$tienda.name}" select="selected"> {$tienda.name}</option>
                    {/foreach}
            </select>
            <div class="row boton_grabar_envio">
                <button type="submit" value="add" class="button btn btn-default boton_borde" name="op" id="boton_grabar_envio">
                    <span>
                        {l s='Grabar bulto'}
                        <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>

                <button type="submit" value= "del" class="button btn btn-default boton_borde" name="op" id="boton_restar_envio">
                    <span>
                        {l s='Restar bulto'}
                        <i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i>
                    </span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

En el archivo donde recibes el formulario puedes controlar que botón has pulsado con `isset`:

```
if (isset($_POST["remBulto"]) {
  //to do
} else if (isset($_POST["addBulto"]) {
  //to do
}
```

Comment: Si, pero el formulario no me manda, rem o add, la cosa es que cuando pulso cualquiera de los dos botones coje el ultimo input en este caso rem y tampoco me recoge el valor del select

Comment: David en el select tienes que quitar el el select="selected" de todas las opciones, sólo debe aparecer selected (no select="selected") en la seleccionada, por eso no te está enviando el valor. Por otro lado al pulsar un botón tipo submit envías todo el formulario, y puedes recoger el valor de todos los campos, cómo gestionas esos valores (si sumas o restas) es lo que harías en el to do del correspodiente botón al procesar el formulario.

Comment: Muchas gracias Carmen, lo he conseguido solucionar. Me has dado una buena idea que realizar.

Comment: Para eso estamos